# How does Android scrollview work internally?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I am very curious to understand how does ScrollView work. ScrollView does many interesting things like displaying only portion of its whole content and making it move based on user's touch events.

I tried reading the `..../Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-29/android/widget/ScrollView.java` to understand ScrollView's internal mechanism but it's too complex for me to grasp. Can someone break it down to its fundamentals and explain how does it work please?

If I were to write my own scroll view how should I do it, and what fundamental concepts should I understand about Android's UI internal mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

Most important points:

1. It overrides `public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` which is responsible for starting actual touch event when user starts dragging.
2. When intercept returns true `ScrollView` takes the touch event and `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` starts being called. It simply tracks drag distance and calculates any flings done by the user.
3. During drag or fling animation `public void scrollTo(int x, int y)` is called. This is the core method that effectively applies visible offset to all children.

Source file itself is quite complex because it handles edge cases and more "boring" stuff like keyboard scrolling, focus navigation, accessibility events etc.